# What character represent "Enter" for serial communication?

Tags: serial-port, ascii, arduino

I am trying to send a serial command using my Arduino, but I can't find out how to replicate the `Enter` key.  I've tried `\r\n` as well as `\n` and neither of those seem to do it.

I've tried the Arduino functions `Serial.write()` `Serial.print()` `Serial.println()` and none of those work either.

What can I use to replicate the `Enter` key?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try `\r`
It has the ASCII 0xD(13) and it's called [Carriage Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

Comment: 0x0D is 13; not 12

Answer (score 0):

In general, it depends on the application that is processing the key press. From the keyboard, the typical scan code 0x1C is sent to the application for the Enter key (and 0x9C on release).

In PuTTY (related to OP's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997108/what-does-putty-send-when-i-press-enter-key)), it sends ASCII CR (carriage return) 0x0D only, even on Windows machines.