# What does PuTTY send when I press Enter key?

Tags: arduino, ascii, putty, control-characters

I am trying desperately to get a Bluetooth dongle working with my Arduino but I can't send it a command that it needs.  I can use it when I plug it into my computer via a USB to UART chip and send the command (`C`) from PuTTY and then press `Enter`.

The Bluetooth dongle's [command sheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-bluetooth-um.pdf) says that the command I am trying to send it `C<cr>` but I can't figure out how to send the proper carriage return character from the Arduino code.  I have tried using the `Serial.println()` function as well as adding the `\r` character to my current `Serial.write("C\r")` but neither of those are working.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check your Putty terminal settings to see what it's set up to send; you can configure it to send whatever line endings you want.

Comment: @Wooble Where is the "PuTTY Reconfiguration" would I be able to find that?

Answer (score 14):

Interestingly, I can report the opposite on Win 7: PuTTY for me and my embedded project is sending ONLY `\r` over the COM port. Curious, read: frustratingly unexplainable, but I simply look for either character on the other end of the serial connection.

Then, if you enable "Implicit LF in every CR" under Terminal options it will send both `\r\n`.  Default behaviour seems to be akin to a Commodore machine :D (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). who knew...

Comment: Just ran into this, thanks for mentioning the implicit LF setting.

Comment: I just ran into this too. I'm really glad I checked first before hooking it to my PIC; as everyone else's post shows, this is quite unexpected. My scope clearly shows that Putty's default is to send \r only. This is not documented.

Comment: @carveone, I found the docs [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-telnet), see sec. 4.6.14:<br/>
By default, PuTTY sends the Telnet New Line code when you press Return, instead of **sending Control-M as it does in most other protocols.**

Comment: But that should just apply to telnet connections rather than serial ones surely. But this whole thing with \r does explain why I've seen protocols that end in \r rather than \n. It does show that one must be very careful not to assume anything about anything :-) The esp8266 dongle wants both cr-lf and you have to use enter and also ctrl-J. If you google that, you'll see the number of people who've been caught out by that. Enter is CR, not LF...

Comment: No, 'Implicit LF in every CR' doesn't do that. There is no option in original PuTTY to send LF when Enter is pressed.

Answer (score 10):

Sending CR+LF is possible in modified PuTTY. Source code is available at https://github.com/gniemirowski/putty-crlf and Windows binary at https://www.grzegorz.net/pliki/putty-crlf.zip When you run this version just go to Terminal -> Keyboard and select "CR LF" for "The Enter key" option.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

PuTTY emulates xterm which emulates vt100. To have putty send CR/LF when pressing enter, type ESC[20h in putty after connecting to the serial device. This sets VT100 LNM true.

http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html

Line feed/new line  New line    ESC [20h    Line feed   ESC [20l

Comment: This works! But can it be saved in a session, so that I do not have to type it in at every start of a session?

Comment: How exactly do I type "ESC[20h"? Is it 6 letters?

Comment: Escape Key (Esc) [ 2 0 h  (five characters)    
[Control sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence#Control_sequences)

Answer (score 2):

If you watch the ascii table or similar reference you might find interesting: \r ou \x0D

For better understanding, see : http://www.grok2.com/sedfaq6.html

Answer (score 2):

The modified PuTTY is the easiest solution. If you want to stick with the standard PuTTY, there's some other options...
You can send a newline using ctrl+j before pressing enter, but that's a faff.
To automate it, you can use AutoHotKey to change your {ENTER} to ^J{ENTER} when you've got a PuTTY window active:

```
#if WinActive("ahk_exe putty.exe")
    Enter::
        SendInput ^J{Enter}
    Return
#if
```

To do this for just one PuTTY window, you can give AHK the name of the window:

```
#if WinActive("COM8 - PuTTY")
    Enter::
        SendInput ^J{Enter}
    Return
#if
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard configuration (on Windows and Linux) if you type "help" and then press enter, the following chain of bytes will appear on the serial port (checked with external connected terminal via RS232, and logic analyzer):

0x68(h) 0x65(e) 0x6c(l) 0x70(p) 0x0d(CR: Carriage Return U+000D)

So it seems like PUTTY puts CR on ENTER (no matter if you are on Linux or Windows).

Answer (score 1):

On arduino program, just use `Serial.write` and both characters codes:

```
Serial.write(13);    // CR
Serial.write(10);    // LF
```

And Avoid `Serial.print` as it is intended as human readable, so formatted.

references: [write](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) [print](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print)

Answer (score -1):

I'm almost sure that you are looking for the `\n` new line character.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this very simple code (cr = carriage return)

```
Serial.write(13);
```

And because the next "printed" caracters will feed the residual text, it's ok.